# Connect to Old SignalR server from .Net core UI

Tags: typescript, .net-core, signalr

We have an existing SignalR server running on a 4.6.2 framework using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.2.1.

We have a new UI application running .net Core/Angular5/Typescript. The @aspnet/signalr client uses the new protocol and can't connect to our existing SignalR server. Is there a way for us to install an older version of the SignalR client into our .net Core application and still be able to connect to the old Server?

Comment: You cannot mix the old and new. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152486/signalr-version-compatability-statuscode-405-method-not-allowed/49153217?noredirect=1#comment85435635_49153217

Comment: I am not trying to mix old and new. problem is that the server is using old tech, but the new app is .net core. so I need a way to connect to the old server using the new UI app that is written in .net core

Comment: Then I think you need to clarify your question or at least provide some additional information. What do you mean "install an older version of the SignalR client into our .net Core application"?

Comment: I have retrofitted the jquery.signalR-2.2.3.js file into our .net core Angular5 UI project and can connect with the legacy system. Seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix and match version of the SignalR server and client. For SignalR if you're using the ASP.NET Core on the server then you have to use it on the client as well.

From the [MSDN SignalR alpha blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/)

> SignalR for ASP.NET Core is not compatible with previous versions of SignalR. This means that you cannot use the old server with the new clients or the old clients with the new server.

Comment: I am not trying to mix old and new. problem is that the server is using old tech, but the new app is .net core. so I need a way to connect to the old server using the new UI app that is written in .net core

Answer (score 0):

I have retrofitted the jquery.signalR-2.2.3.js file into our .net core Angular5 UI project and can connect with the legacy system.