# SignalR Compatibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a .Net framework 4.7.2 project that is using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR nuget package, not Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR since it's not supported in .Net framework 4.7.2.

For my react client app, I'm not sure which client package I should use.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr

Does the option 2 support .Net framework 4.7.2 as well?

I've tried reading Microsoft documentation but wasn't able to find this information.

Comment: I think you need option 1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Agreed, you do need to use option 1. Option 2 is not compatible nor support .NET 4.x as the .NET CORE version was a complete rewrite. See this for more information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152486/signalr-version-compatability-statuscode-405-method-not-allowed